# Xampp control panel is not showing

Tags: xampp, windows-10

My Xampp control panel is not showing in the desktop (Windows 10), but can only up the servers through the shortcut (minimized option in the task bar).

As follows:

[image: xampp control panel in taskbar]

I have close the application without stopping the servers, will that be the case of this matter?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Here it's the easiest solution.

1. Right-click **xampp.exe** and go to **xampp** folder
2. Find and delete the following files `xampp-control.ini - xampp-control.log`
3. Restart **xampp**

Comment: I don't know why this answer is here below since it the proper fix to the problem and not a temporary workaround. Thanks

Comment: @mstation probably because this answer came later on than the others.

(+1) this answer solved my problem with xampp control panel in windows 8 where an icon shows in the system tray but the context menu won't appear even if the icon is right-clicked.

Comment: This should be the right answer, solved my problem completely

Comment: this is the proper right answer, no more modifications and hover maximize etc.

Comment: This is certainly a quick fix, but deleting the xampp-control.ini might also delete other custom settings. If so then better to edit the [WindowSettings] values, easy enough. If there aren't any customizations this is definitely the fastest, easiest solution.

Comment: you dont need to delete the whole file, just delete the lines with "window settings"

Comment: Worked Like a charm

Comment: While this is a nice fix, it will remove all of other XAMPP preferences. I will suggest 
Juan Carlos Ibarra answer.

Answer (score 43):

1. Close Xampp process.
2. Go and open `C://xampp/xampp-control.ini`
3. Change these properties from x-number to 0

   [image]
4. Restart Xampp.

This worked for me.

Comment: This is probably the correct solution for most users; worked for me, and I know why: The XAMPP control panel was on another monitor when the system was shut down. When restarted, XAMPP still thought the panel was on that monitor. Resetting the window position did the trick.

Comment: Thanks @MQuiggGeorgia.

Comment: Thank you so much for this helpful answer! It really got me out of a hole

Comment: This will work but you must be careful because it will also depend you resolution. Easier and better option would be to delete the ini files and restart.

Answer (score 25):

There is also one temporary solution.

1. Open XAMPP, You cannot see its window but its icon will be shown in the windows task bar.
2. Hover your mouse over the XAMPP icon, a small popup will be shown.
3. Right click on popup and choose maximize. This will maximize the XAMPP Control Panel and you can see all the options and logs.

This fix is temporary and you may have to do repeat the steps often.

Comment: Great solution. Easy and faast

Comment: Great solution. and its not temporary. It solved issue permanently

Comment: After step 3, the window shows up, you may use the mouse to adjust the window size instead of clicking its "restore down" button (that will cause the window to disappear again). Then the window will be working properly. You can minimize it and click the icon to make it reappear.

Comment: I tried all the solutions above. But this is the one that worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

This may be too late, but I had the same issue for some time, I will share my workaround, it is not a permanent fix but it works, you have to use procexp from SysinternalsSuite https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/
you launch procexp.exe, you search form xampp-control.exe and right click> window> Maximize.[image]

Comment: it works,but the view will not be like the original after `maximizing`.I think may be some issue with the `UI`.Thanks

Comment: You can drag it from the top and resize it when you begin to drag it, it gets too small, but again you resize it, I know, it's crazy and annoying ... I think xampp has not an update system in place so if we want to fix it, we have to reinstall it manually .... or reverse engineer the binary and make it start with Maximized flag =/

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Comment: You can also kill the process httpd using procexp.exe then double click again xampp

Comment: @user1692823 bad idea, there are other answers that may be ok but definitely, Ramadan's solution is bad, it resets some configuration when you delete the .ini file, you definitely don't wanna do that, my friend.

Comment: @Melardev I apologize. i deleted my comment since it might put people on the wrong foot.

Answer (score 6):

Only 3 Steps:

1. Open XAMPP
2. Rollover over on XAMPP icon until the popup window comes up.
3. Right click on the popup window and select Maximize.

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: This is the correct non-invasive solution. Maximise then just drag it back to the centre.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the XAMPP window was just outside of my screen.
I just had to select it in the taskbar, press `Alt+Space`, `Move` and bring back the window using the arrow keys

Comment: Thanks.. This worked for me since I dont have admin privilage to change xampp-control.ini file

Answer (score 5):

Clicking on xampp-control file in xampp folder (in my case it's in C:/xampp folder) will open XAMPP control panel.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open XAMPP
2. Hover over the XAMPP icon until the popup window comes up.
3. Right click on the popup window and choose "maximize". This will display the XAMPP control panel in fullscreen mode.
4. In full screen click and hold on the toolbar at the top and then drag it down until the control panel is in a re sizable view and release.
5. You should now be able to minimize, maximize, or re size the panel with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Below steps works for me.

1) Open XAMPP, from taskbar right click on popup shown on mouse over of the XAMPP icon.

2) Select maximize, it will show XAMPP control panel in maximize mode.

3) Select topbar of the XAMPP and drag it down it will reset the size and that's it.

Now next time, when you open XAMPP it will show on the same location where you closed XAMPP previously.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't involve modifying, uninstalling, editing, or anything overtly complicated, just hovering:

1. Start XAMPP.
2. Hover mouse over XAMPP Window Tab until Window preview pane pops up over the tab.
3. Right Click over preview pane and click maximize.
4. Drag down from the sides to resize. Clicking the minimize tab will cause the window to disappear, and you will have to repeat the first three steps.  Drag down from the top to pop the window out of maximized size.

Comment: That works for me... I had to drag the control panel window to a side border then I was able to resize it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very easy way in windows 10. check this out!

1. Open "Windows Task Manager"
2. Go to "Processes" tab
3. Expand the "xampp-control.exe"
4. Right Click on Expanded "XAMPP Control Panel"
5. Select "Maximize"

Then you'll get Xampp Control Panel.

Note - The 5th step will only shown if the app is hidden.
[image: Works same in the Xampp.]

Comment: There is no option for `Maximize`

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest one thing. I had this situation. I solved that following the steps.

1. Restart the computer.
2. open taskbar to see if xampp is running.
3. Stop xampp if it is running.
4. Start xampp.
5. It will again minimize in the system tray just double click on the xampp icon.

Maybe this will help thanks.

Comment: did as you mentioned,but nothing happened.same as earlier.I think this is a bug of `xamp`

Comment: Yeah it could be.

Answer (score 1):

Or try this:

It may be that the control panel position has been saved 'off screen'. This can happen if screen resolution has changed, or if a monitor has removed or changed.

To reset position:

1-Right click xampp.exe and go to xampp folder

2-Find and open xampp-control.ini with an editor, such as notepad.

3 Under [WindowSettings] are the settings for left and top position, plus width and height. Left and Top are pixel values for the control panel from the top left corner of your screen. If either of these are negative values the control panel will be off screen at default settings

4 Set them to something like:
Left=200 
Top=200

Leave the width and height settings as they are, save the changes.

This should get the panel in view on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

1. Quit Xampp
2. Delete xampp-control.ini file in xampp installation folder
3. Start Xampp

Answer (score 1):

There is also one temporary solution.

Open XAMPP, In the windows task bar.
Hover your mouse over the XAMPP icon, a small popup will be shown.
Right click on popup and choose size. 
click and pull bottom to resize window xampp controll.

This fix is temporary and you may have to do repeat the steps often.

Answer (score 1):

Go to xampp directory and right click on xampp-control.exe than click on pin to start. it will appear in start bar you can pin it into task bar also

Answer (score 1):

Go to the directory where xampp is installed for example if it's installed on drive C://
go C:\xampp folder and look for xampp-control.exe. right click and pin it to start or send it to desktop

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem but the solution is quite simple that worked perfectly for me 
you must have the **xampp** directory inside the C: drive or wherever your installation location is
1: open up xampp folder from C:
2:scroll all the way down you will see **xampp-control**
3:Right click and Pin to start

Answer (score 1):

Go to your XAMPP might be in the C folder or D depending on the installation, installation folder.
At the bottom find xampp-control.exe file.
Right click on that file and select "Pin To Start"

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution I found was:

1. Click on task view.
2. Click on minimized window of the control panel.
3. Just resize like any other window.

Deleting the log and config file doesn't work for me. So this could be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem of having the Control Panel hiding in the [Hidden Icons] in my Windows 10 PC. It didn't happen all the time. Once awhile, you might even get multiple XAMPP in the taskbar if you tried to open another XAMPP panel but none of them would open up.

Here is my simple solution.

1. Do whatever to stop and close the XAMPP that are hiding and running (in taskbar)
2. Go to c:\xampp (where the application was installed).
3. Delete two files: xampp-control.ini and xampp-control.log
4. Restart the XAMPP, which would ask to set the language.
5. That's it!

Seem to me the problem is due to an old version of xampp-control.ini stuck in the folder.

(XAMPP Version 8.1.6, Control Panel v3.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I did was try this suggestion and then run using Administrator, didn't have the same problem again, between just try with Run as Administrator as I read in logs it needed Administrator permission.

Try this:

1-Right click xampp.exe and go to xampp folder

2-Find and delete xampp-control.ini, log

3-Restart xampp

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was checking for windows updates and installing them

Answer (score 0):

1. Quit Xampp
2. Open Xampp installation folder
3. Open **xampp-control.ini** with an editor
4. Find **[WindowSettings]**
5. Set all filed of WindowSettings ( Left, Top, Width, Height ) to ' **-1** '
6. Save file
7. Start Xampp again

**Example:**

```
[WindowSettings]
Left=-1
Top=-1
Width=-1
Height=-1
```

Comment: Thank you! It saves my life!

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour

1. Go to **xampp** Directory.
2. Delete the **xampp-control.ini** file
3. Restart your xampp and it will work.

Merci!!

Comment: Not useful, this will also delete all your custom settings...

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "`Start Control Panel Minimized`" in the **configuration**

Answer (score 0):

Simply bring up the task  manager, go to Xampp and **"bring to front"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) localhost, double clicking **`xampp-control.exe`** have no effect.

But when I use the *clip* and issue the command:

```
C:\Users\username>C:\xampp\xampp-control.exe
```

*xampp-control* services seems to get started as observed from the *hidden icon* tray.

[image: xampp-control]

But the process isn't observed either through *Task Manager's* **`Processes`** or **`Services`** tab,

But, second time issuing the same command through *clip*, the **XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.4** shows up just perfect.

[image: xampp-control_displayed]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you install xampp not in the c drive, this happens

Answer (score -1):

Open Xamp installation folder (Windows >> `C:\xampp\`)

1. Quit Xampp (right click on icon tray)
2. Delete `xampp-control.ini` file in xamp installation folder
3. Start Xampp again