# Xampp control panel appears to be uninstalling itself on Windows

Tags: xampp, windows-installer

Since last 5-6 times installation I was able to notice that after xampp control panel new installation it works fine when it's installed but whenever I do a restart of my system, the Xampp control panel installation disappears. It appears it's automatically uninstalled on restart and no icon is shown.

Comment: Are you able to edit this question to make the problem reproducible for readers? If not, it may be hard for readers to answer it. What does "disappearing" mean in the case of a control panel? Is this a GUI window running in a Xampp Windows application?

Comment: @halfer : "disappear" means usually when we install any software we are able to see software icon in the startup menu section, this thing is not happening in my case when I restart my system, as it automatically get uninstalled.

Comment: I have tried to make this clearer in the question, do feel free to keep editing.

Comment: Are you sure that it is uninstalled, rather than perhaps just not auto-starting? Maybe it needs to be configured to appear on system boot.

Comment: Okay I checked it now, it seems I have to go to xampp folder and then click on xampp-control.exe it works fine. But usually icon gets added on installation of new software, which is not happening after installation.

Comment: Now, apache and mysql services started successfully. but it's not rendering default xampp page. :(

Answer (score 0):

***Existing Answers***: I am not familiar with Xampp I am afraid, hence the below could be clear-off-its-rocker as they say :-):

- I have written before about [disappearing installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373972/installed-program-is-removed-automatically-everytime-when-server-restarts-from-w/57380860#57380860) and likely and unlikely causes.
- There is also this previous answer from someone else: **[Xampp control panel is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46627164/xampp-control-panel-is-not-showing)**
- **UPDATE**: What do you know, I found two earlier answer that I think are better:

  - [Force file to autostart with Windows in VS's MSI setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640799/force-file-to-autostart-with-windows-in-vss-msi-setup/56653034#56653034)
  - [Uninstall Custom Action Not Deleting Registry Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216281/uninstall-custom-action-not-deleting-registry-key/48426736#48426736)

***Autoruns***: Try the [Autoruns tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) described in point 4 of the above link (first one at the top). This allows you to see whatever is set to auto-start when your system boots. There is a plethora of ways to make things launch on boot. One way is to use the "**`Startup folders`**" (described below). But you can also run as a **`service`**, a **`scheduled task`**, as a **`driver or codec`**, kicked off from **`run-once`** or **`run-keys`** in the registry or a number of other ways. Get the free [Autoruns tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) and try it to see. I think there are even further options not shown by that tool to auto-start.

***Task Manager & CCleaner***: You can also see the "Startup" tab in the native task manager in later versions of Windows. Not nearly as many details, but you can at least check it. Tools such as CCleaner also show startup entries.

> ***Startup Folders***: There is the age-old concept of startup folders for shortcuts pointing to binaries. These are still around in Windows
>   10, but I am not sure if they are supposed to be used anymore. There
>   is a personal one per user, and a shared one for all users (at least,
>   there could be more):
>
> - ***Personal***: **`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`**.
> - ***All Users***: **`%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`**.
>
> Putting shortcuts here should start your binaries on Windows startup (unless
>   they need elevation and such things - then I suppose you would get an elevation prompt - not at all good).

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling all virtual machines applications in your desktop if you have any. And try to make sure you XAMPP control panel is compatible with your current desktop specs.