# XAMPP control panel is not showing on Mac

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, xampp-vm

My XAMPP(7.4.7-0) control panel is not showing on Mac (Big Sur beta 2 2020.07.08).

I've known it also can be a problem to Catalina by searching.The whole windows of software is transparent. And seems the program is actually working. If I click the the area where a quit button should be, I can still close it.

This problem also appears on Windows 10 and has been solved very well, the link is here. But I cannot find the corresponding files and operations on Mac version.

[Xampp control panel is not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46627164/xampp-control-panel-is-not-showing)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A solution as complementary is to download the VM version of XAMPP instead of the normal version. Its panel shows well on Mac OS Big Sur.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of BIG SUR, it does not show the XAMPP-VM control panel and any other version of XAMPP

Comment: quite weird.... It might relevant to the personal configuration of Mac Big Sur maybe? Apple should try to fix all the softwares that cannot run on the new system... Well I'm not pretty sure... Just wait for the update of final version of Big Sur perhaps

Comment: Yes, I waited for this update. I installed a new update but it didn't solve the problem.  I don't know what it can be.